# Janrain and IOS 5 Compatibility

Tags: ios5, openid, janrain

Is the Janrain iOS library for Engage compatible with IOS 5?

Comment: If this does not answer your question, please elaborate with a comment.  If your question is answered, please accept the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Yes I meant Engage, but I already looked at those pages and they don't  specify what version of IOS it works with. I tried installing Engage on my phone and I had to do all kinds of crazy thinks like change the compiler, etc before it would even run, and once I got it running it just shows the login screen, but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am just getting started with the Engage iOS SDK too. The instructions on the Janrain site are **not** for iOS 5 / Xcode 4. They are targeted at earlier versions of iOS running under Xcode 3.  It is still possible to drag/drop the JREngage source folder into your project. The trick is to **not** use a project that has ARC enabled. When you enable ARC you will get all sorts of compiler errors and warnings and it will fail to build.  If you create a new project in Xcode 4 and uncheck the *Use Automatic Reference Counting* option it should build okay.

I have submitted a support request to Janrain in hopes of getting some clarification on whether this is expected behavior and what their plans are for supporting ARC.  When I get a response I will update my comment here.

Here is the response I received from Janrain. It looks like the Engage SDK does not build with ARC enabled, but following their suggested steps you can have it built without ARC within a project that does use ARC.

> To use ARC with the Janrain Engage for iOS library, please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to your project settings, select your application's target(s) and click the "Build Phases" tab
> 2. Expand the section named "Compile Sources"
> 3. Select all the files from the JREngage library, including SFHFKeychainUtils.m and JSONKit.m
> 4. Hit **Enter**, to edit all the files at once, and in the floating text box add the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag

Comment: New documentation is being released that describes iOS 5 & Xcode 4 integration.  It's slated to be live the 21st. You will be able to find it at http://rpxnow.com/docs/iphone